# Conditional concerning a selected tag not working

Tags: php, conditional-content

I'm trying to print some content in all the posts under a certain author only if a specific tag (default wp taxonomy) is set

the tag is "animali permessi"
here is the code

```
$posttags = 'animali permessi';

if (isset($posttags)) {
$supplemento_animali = '<div class="suppl_animali">'. get_the_author_meta( 'supplemento_animali', $post->post_author ) .'</div>';
}


$content = $content . $titolo_prezzo_include . $locazione  .  $commissione . $consumi . $pulizia_inc . $biancheria_inc . $ac_inc .  $titolo_prezzo_non_include . $pulizia_esc . $tassa_soggiorno . $supplemento_animali . $supplemento_culla . $importo_cauzione . $servizio_spiaggia . $suppl_soggiorni_brevi . $biancheria_esc . $asciugamani_esc . $wi_fi_esc . $ac_esc .  $saldo . '<footer class="author_bio_section" >'. $author_details . $titolo_affitti . $periodo_affitti . $titolo_orari . $orari .'</footer>';
}
return $content;
}
```

The code is fine except for the condition
The purpose is printing the "extra charge for pets" only if in each post is set the tag "animali permessi" (pets allowed)

Comment: `isset` isn't a WordPress function, it has nothing to do with post tags, it's a PHP function to see if a variable exists/is set

Answer (score 3):

[`isset()`](https://php.net/isset) checks to see if a variable is set, ie, has a value other than `null`. The way you're using it will *always* return `true` because you've set `$posttags` to `'animali permessi'`, which is not `null`.

I think you're looking for the WordPress function [`has_tag()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_tag/) instead.

```
if (has_tag( 'animali permessi', $post ) ) {
    $supplemento_animali = '<div class="suppl_animali">'. get_the_author_meta( 'supplemento_animali', $post->post_author ) .'</div>';
}
```

Comment: note that you can use this without `$post` if it's used inside the loop